# Running Javascript along side C# using Blazor in headless browser

Tags: javascript, .net-core, blazor, cefsharp, webassembly

I'm trying to build a .NET core application that execute JavaScript, this JavaScript also need to call C# functions on CLR objects as well ,I used JINT (https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) but it has one majeure disadvantage which i couldn't debug any JavaScript code.
So thinking for alternative that using CEF sharp that will run Blazor to execute javascript alongside C#. is it possible ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSInterop in blazor to communicate between JS and C#.

Read more here for calling JS from C#:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0

And here for calling C# from JS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what if I want to run headless not via ASP.net , is CEF sharp can run Blazor? Think about I have class foo with method called HelloWorld in c#  and I would like to call this method from javascript.

Comment: That method must be static to be accessible via javascript. See this https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-dotnet-from-javascript/